# I need to set the path of an excel worksheet so that I can use a relative path to load a dll

Tags: excel, vba, dll

My excel spreadsheet works fine when the dll has an absolute path, but when it is in the same directory and I don't specify a path, just put the name of the dll, it can't find it.

When I try

```
Debug.Print CurDir
C:\TEMP\TestAPSOutput\Simple2Room
```

But that's not right. How can I reset this to point at the directory of the actual spreadsheet, and therefore hopefully load the dll?

Thanks,
James

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
 Dim PathCrnt As String

 PathCrnt = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path
```

I use this all the time to find files I have placed in the same folder as the workbook.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. Problem is how can I use this to then load the dll. Wouldn't I need to put this in a worksheet_open method and then use PathCrnt to set a system variable. I've tried building strings on the line                                                                     Public Declare PtrSafe Function SetSourceDescription Lib "MyDll.dll" (ByVal Key As String) As Long                                                                 I'm using excel 2010 64-bit

Comment: Sorry but some else will have to help you with the next bit of your problem.

Comment: Solved using     chdir  ActiveWorkbook.Path      beware things like loading files, as that can pull your current directory away from where it's supposed to be.